How you handle multiple connection strings in postgres?
When you have a SaaS app and you have different connection strings, how you handle the connection for each tenant ? And you create every time a new connection or ? So how you can handle this efficently ?

Why do you have different connection strings for each tenant? But yes, it's unavoidable to create a separate connection for each.

Which database library do you use? Do you want to use pooling?

@Bergi yes, I currently use pg-promise but I also can switch to pg libary

Are the connection strings completely different (including db, role, password) or only host part is different?

@PavloGolub only host part

For host-only difference part, the connection string supports multi-host specification, although the underlying driver still doesn't support it, as far as I know. So, you can maintain separate connection pools, or switch to another driver.

@wepro01 Are you saying each tenant has not just their own database, but their own database cluster (on a different host)?
